# videoplayer with download button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, download, swift4, video-player

I have a video player , and i want to add a download button.
How can i add this button to my video player or create a button to download that video.
tanks.
My code is :

```
let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
playerViewController.player!.play()
```

Comment: @AhmadF I want to download all this video to my desktop. A button to download a link like this : ("https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")

Comment: You can using Media Cache 
https://github.com/vitoziv/VIMediaCache

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check this below code, The download is proceeded in a background thread, so will not affect the UI.

```
class func downloadVideo(videoImageUrl:String)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        let url=NSURL(string: videoImageUrl)
        let urlData=NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        if((urlData) != nil)
        {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

            let fileName = videoImageUrl.lastPathComponent //.stringByDeletingPathExtension

            let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName)"

            //saving is done on main thread

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                 urlData?.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
            })

        }
    })

}
```

For calling above function in a button target.

```
Self.downloadVideo("https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
```

Comment: Yes. But that would be comparingly slow.

Comment: well its worth a try though

Comment: with a little change this code worked. tanks @DHEERAJ